# Not understanding array merging procedure in merge sort procedure

Tags: sorting, mergesort

I've been trying to learn the procedure for merging two arrays in merge sort, and I've been given a fixed code which I have to strictly follow .The following is a program for sorting a list of numbers in ascending/ descending order depending on the user's choice is as follows:

```
 const
    max = 200000;
    MaxDisp = 20;
type
    list = array[1..max] of real;
var
  a: list;
  na: longint;
  is_asc:boolean;
procedure GenList(var L: list; n: longint);
  var
    i: longint;
  begin
    randomize;
    for i := 1 to n do begin
      L[i] := random;
    end;
  end;
procedure DispList(L: list; n: longint);
  var
    i: longint;
  begin
    for i := 1 to MaxDisp do begin
      if i <= n then begin
        writeln(i:10, ' - ', L[i]:0:10);
      end;
    end;
    if n > MaxDisp then begin
      writeln(n - MaxDisp, ' more ...');
    end;
  end;
procedure sort(var L: list; n: longint;is_asc:boolean);
    procedure Merge(L1,L2,R1,R2:longint);
    var
      M:list;//this is C
      i1,i2,iM,i,j:longint;
    begin
        i1:=L1;
        i2:=L2;
        j:=1;
        while (i1<=R1) and (i2<=R2) do begin
            if (is_asc and (L[i1]<L[i2])) or not is_asc and (L[i1]<L[i2]) then begin
                M[j]:=L[i1];
                j:=j+1;
                i1:=i1+1;
            end
            else begin
                M[j]:=L[i2];
                j:=j+1;
                i2:=i2+1;
            end;
            j:=________;
        end;
        if(i1>R1) and (i2<=R2) then
            for i:=________ do begin
                M[j]:=_______;
            end
        else if (i2>R2) and (i1<=R1) then
            for i:=1 to _______ do begin
                _________;
            end;
        num:=_______;
        i:=______;
        for j:=1 to num do begin
            _________;
        end
    end;
    procedure MSort(LL,RR:longint);
    var mid:integer;
    begin
        if LL<RR then begin
            mid:=(LL+RR) div 2;
            MSort(LL,mid);
            MSort(mid+1,RR);
            Merge(LL,mid,mid+1,RR);
        end
    end;
begin
    MSort(1,n);
end;
function is_sorted(L: list; n:longint;is_asc:boolean): boolean;
  var
    i: longint;
    flag: boolean;
  begin
    flag := true;
    i := 1;
    while flag and (i < n) do begin
      flag := ((L[i]<=L[i+1]) and (is_asc)) or (not(is_asc) and (L[i]>=L[i+1]));
      i := i + 1;
    end;
    is_sorted := flag;
  end;

begin
  na := MaxDisp;
  GenList(a, na);
  writeln(na, ' random items:');
  DispList(a, na);
  writeln('Press <Enter> to sort the list in ascending order ...');
  readln;
  sort(a, na,is_asc);
  DispList(a, na);
  writeln('Sorted in ascending order: ', is_sorted(a, na,is_asc));
  write('Press <Enter> to continue ...');
  readln;
end.
```

Except for the blank parts, I understand what the other parts of the code are doing, including the first part of the procedure Merge, which I think is just merging the arrays in L into M, and I think the following part is writing about the cases in case i1 and i2 are larger than L1 and L2, but I don't understand what the problem if this happens or what should be done. After this the following parts of the procedure Merge I have no idea what it is supposed to be doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know this language (indexes start at 1?), but this is what I think needs changing:

```
        i1:=L1;
        i2:=L2;
        j:=1;
        while (i1<=R1) and (i2<=R2) do begin
            if (is_asc and (L[i1]<L[i2])) or not is_asc and (L[i1]<L[i2]) then begin
                M[j]:=L[i1];
                j:=j+1;
                i1:=i1+1;
            end
            else begin
                M[j]:=L[i2];
                j:=j+1;
                i2:=i2+1;
            end;
            // j:=________;              // don't change j
        end;
        while(i1 <= R1) do begin         // copy rest of run 1 if any elements
            M[j]:=L[i1];
            j:=j+1;
            i1:=i1+1;
        end
        while(i2 <= R2) do begin         // copy rest of run 2 if any elements
            M[j]:=L[i2];
            j:=j+1;
            i2:=i2+1;
        end
        for(i = 1 to j) do begin         // copy M back into L
            L[i+L1-1] := M[j];           // I'm not sure about the -1
        end
    end;
```